# Self Join Condition fails in PHP but works in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this strange situation and not sure of what is wrong. I have a simple self join to find matches based on some conditions. I have this query running fine in mysql but when I call it through PHP, it doesn't return any values.

```
select * from Requests p inner join Requests c on c.ID<>p.ID
where usr_ID<>4
and p.c_ID = c.c_ID
```

This works fine but not the below one.

```
DB::table('Requests as parent')
  ->join('Requests as child', 'parent.ID', '<>', 'child.ID')
  ->where('parent.usr_ID', '<>', 4)
  **->where('parent.c_ID', '=', 'child.c_ID')**
  ->get();
```

In the above query, if I remove the second where condition(c_ID), it returns correct values. For all rows, this has a value of 1. If I replace child.c_ID or parent.c_ID by 1, it works again. I have tried with other columns as well and found the same issue.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the query builder makes out of your second where condition is:

```
WHERE parent.c_ID = 'child.c_ID'
```

So instead of a "normal" `where()` use `whereRaw()`, which takes your input and injects it right into the final SQL query

```
->whereRaw('parent.c_ID = child.c_ID')
```

Alternatively you could also use `DB::raw()` on the third argument

```
->where('parent.c_ID', '=', DB::raw('child.c_ID'))
```

Both are essentially the same so use whichever you like more.

Comment: Thanks lukasgeiter for quick reply. That seems to work but I have similar conditions in all the places and they were working fine except for this self join. Do I need to change all of them?

Comment: By the way, this is my first project on LAMP stack. I was stuck with Microsoft all this while.

Comment: You're welcome. It depends... You need to update all the conditions where two columns are compared. because laravel tries to evaluate the second (or third) parameter as a value and not a column name. Know what I mean?

Comment: Yes I got the point. I will check thoroughly and make the changes if required. Thanks once again.

Comment: Does the LIKE operator work in this case? ->where('parent.c_ID', 'like', '%'. DB::raw('child.c_ID').'%'). I have tried it but its not working. It works with the value though.

Comment: Of course! `whereRaw` accepts everything that works with your database server ;)